# MYSQL update query with >= and <= not working

Tags: php, mysql

I want to update certain fields in a database table and i'm trying to use the `<=` and `>=` 
It gives back an error.

This is my query

```
 $update_kooi = "UPDATE tbl_inschrijvingen 
                 SET tbl_inschrijvingen.KMid = '".$keurmeester."'
                 WHERE (((tbl_inschrijvingen.Kooinummer) >= '".$kooi1."' 
                       OR <= '".$kooi2."'))";
```

It must update those fields which are between to posted values.

Can somebody help me?

Thnax

Comment: what type is the field `Kooinummer`? What's the exact error?

Comment: Kooinummer must be a number and there is no need to put them in single quoute

Comment: Aside from the syntax error (you're using `OR <= somevalue` rather than `OR somecol <= somevalue`), to update rows where the number is between two other numbers you must either use `BETWEEN` as some of the answers suggest, or `AND` (you're using `OR`, which will actually select all non-null numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 'Between' like

```
UPDATE tbl_inschrijvingen 
SET tbl_inschrijvingen.KMid = '".$keurmeester."'
WHERE (((tbl_inschrijvingen.Kooinummer) 
    between '".$kooi1."' and  '".$kooi2."'))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your query look simple there are too many `( )` making it very confusing

```
$update_kooi = 
"UPDATE tbl_inschrijvingen 
SET tbl_inschrijvingen.KMid = '".$keurmeester."'
WHERE 
( tbl_inschrijvingen.Kooinummer >= '".$kooi1."' OR tbl_inschrijvingen.Kooinummer <= '".$kooi2."')";
```

You were trying as

```
(
 ( 
   ( col) >= 'some val' or <= 'someval' 
 )
)
```

Which is not the correct way.

You can also use `between` as

```
where col between va1 AND va2
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer but it wil update all records not just the selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update_kooi = "UPDATE tbl_inschrijvingen SET tbl_inschrijvingen.KMid = $keurmeester
            WHERE (tbl_inschrijvingen.Kooinummer BETWEEN $kooi1 AND $kooi2)";
```